# IE inputs without borders

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

So, I've been trying to fix a terrible bug in Internet Explorer (duh) that is affecting my system, but I cant think anything else that I could do to fix it.

I have a few inputs in a jQuery UI Dialog, and for some reason they are being displayed without borders! The borders only appears after I move the cursor through them. I dont have to keep the `hover`, neither keep the input focused: just passing the cursor is enough to get borders rendered.

[image: Example]

The inputs are correctly displayed in Chrome and Firefox, for example, and I tried some things like:

- Giving the input an `outline` in CSS- The result is terrible and the bug persists;
- Added  `!important` to the border property in CSS - No changes;
- Added a `background-color` (for testing only) - Still no changes;

Just for acknowledge, there was a previous bug on the modal, in which some parts of it would be rendered with a transparent background, making it look 50% white bg and 50% transparent, for example. I managed to fix that by adding a background-color property to the modal body and title, in CSS.

Any tips?

EDIT: I'm using jQuery UI 1.9.2

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: Can we see your code please

Comment: A specific part of the code? Or just the modal with some fields?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Just the code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just tried to isolate the problem, but the system requires too many references (css and js imports) to work, therefore, I'm not able to properly reproduce it on jsFiddle :(

Comment: Maybe can you provide a link to a test site?

Comment: Hmm guys, I figured out that it has to be something with my pc, probably with the video card drivers. I just ran the application at browserstack to check the behaviour in another virtual machine, and it worked perfectly. I'm marking this as the answer, and if I find out something else, I'll update the answer. 
Thanks a lot anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it has to be something with my pc, probably with the video card drivers.

I just ran the application at browserstack.com to check the behaviour in another virtual machine, and it worked perfectly. I'm marking this as the answer, and if I find out something else, I'll update the answer.

Thanks!